# How to modify MacOS Dock shortcuts/hotkeys?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, dock

I want to `modify/change/add` `MacOS Dock shortcuts/hotkeys`.

e.g., of a shortcut that is available by default:

- Option-Click on Dock app icon of an app that is not currently open = Hide the currently active app and then Open the app that was clicked
  (from: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21922?locale=en_US)

One very specific ability that I want:

- Open and then Hide an app
- Shift-Click on Dock app icon = Open and then Hide that app
  (or use another easy modifier-key-combo with the click)

I am aware of the bash command `open -a App --hide` (e.g., `open -a TextEdit --hide`). I want to implement this exact functionality with a convenient Dock shortcut like the one mentioned above. If you're wondering "why?": sometimes I just want to open an app because I know that I will need it soon, but I'm still busy with another app, so just open this second app and then immediately hide it so it doesn't get in my way while I'm still busy with that first app.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

These keyboard bindings are built into the Dock application, and cannot be modified.

Comment: OK. Are you aware of any other way to implement that functionality? (Maybe modify the default Dock app icon context menu?)

Comment: No. The Dock is rather resistant to modification in current versions of Mac OS X. You're probably best off getting used to the existing shortcuts, rather than trying to create your own.

Answer (score 0):

The Mac utility program, Keyboard Maestro, does what you've asked, with shortcut keys, without using the Dock:

- open, then immediately hide/minimize
- option+open

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a related solution: (in case anyone is interested)

- an AppleScript App that presents a pick list

Method:

1. create a plain text document containing a list of the apps you want to handle (use correct name, no path, no extension, one name per line, no commas)
2. open 'Script Editor' (/Applications/Utilities)
3. copy-pasta the following code (and edit the first code line for the path to your text file from first step)

   set apps_file to ("path:apps_list.txt")

   set apps_list to paragraphs of (read file apps_file)

   set apps_pick to choose from list apps_list with prompt "Select one or more apps." with multiple selections allowed

   if result is false then return

   set path_base to "Macintosh HD:Applications:"

   set path_msft to path_base & "Microsoft Office 2011:"

   set path_utly to path_base & "Utilities:"

   set spec_msft to "Microsoft"
   set spec_utly to "Activity Monitor, Terminal"

   repeat with apps_this in apps_pick

   ```
   if apps_this contains spec_msft
       set path_this to path_msft
   else if apps_this is in spec_utly
       set path_this to path_utly
   else
       set path_this to path_base
   end if

   set apps_open to path_this & apps_this & ".app"
   run application apps_open
   ```

   end repeat

   return
4. i. navigate menu 'File -> Export...'; ii. use the option 'File Format: Application'; iii. Save; (put the resulting app in your Dock)

Its not quite as convenient as I hoped, but, not too shabby.